# Angular test not passing 100% else path not taken

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this method that I did the tests on it, but it's not 100% because it shows up `else path not taken` . I've already done a test that simulates, the `this.element.nativeElement.classList`
getting something other than "myTest" and after calling the function `myFunction` the `this.element.nativeElement.classList` still with the same class. But still with this problem

```
myFunction() {
    const active = this.element.nativeElement.classList.contains('myTest');
    if (active) { // else path not taken 
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'myTest')
      this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'otherClass')
    }
  }
```

Comment: is it ```mytest``` or ```myTest```?

Comment: thank you, I wrote it wrong when I asked the question, now it's right

Comment: have you tried replacing ```contains``` with ```includes```?

Comment: TypeError: this.element.nativeElement.classList.includes is not a function

Comment: you most likely can do the component logic without accessing the element directly, but to worki with logical model and binde classes instead. but if you don't want to change the solution, than at least provide your test, so the community could help you